# How to run Hadoop on Cygwin with proper credentials to enable setting file permissions, etc.?

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

I cannot change the permissions on files when I run Hadoop in Cygwin:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-James\mapred\staging\James-1143336710\.staging to 0700
```

From what I've gathered you can't really run Cygwin as root since Windows doesn't really have a notion of root ([reference](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-01/msg00338.html)), and I've tried to run Cygwin as the Administrator user but this option isn't available to me when I right click on the Cygwin shortcut in Windows XP (I've also tried changing the Cygwin shortcut's properties to allow me to run as another user but that option is disabled).

Can anyone advise me as to how I can get past this issue?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple-to-use workaround for this particular problem:

https://github.com/congainc/patch-hadoop_7682-1.0.x-win

This issue is not about file permissions per se. Rather, it is an issue with the Java VM's support for setting file permissions on Windows, and an intransigent attitude among the Hadoop committers not to work around the problem. See HADOOP-7682 for the gory details:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7682

Answer (score 0):

run ssh-host-config.  it will set up the prvileged user "cyg_server" and set up sshd
as a windows service.

in "/etc/passwd" give the user a home "/home/cyg_server" and shell "/bin/bash".
create a password for the user.  then create the ssh keys and add them to
~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

start the windows service.  in a cygwin shell, "ssh cyg_server@localhost".

--- edit ---

forgot to mention: when you create the password for the cyg_server user, you need a root cygwin shell (run cygwin bash as Administrator). also give the user a valid shell (/bin/bash).